# how to return from bash function with a message?

Tags: bash

I have a function which calls a command, when the command fails I have to echo a message and then return 1 to signal failure.

EDIT: Sorry I don't remember how my attempt with if was, as other answers have pointed out, I might have done some silly mistake, so I'm removing it.

This one works fine:

```
function F() {
  command || return 1
}
```

but I need to echo message to signal reason for failure, so I tried this, even this doesn't return from function

```
function F() {
  command || (echo "message" && return 1)
}
```

Please suggest right way to do this.

Comment: You say, "looks like `return` returns from `if` block and not from function". No, there is no such thing as returning from an `if` block in bash. Your first snippet should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case:

```
function F() {
  command || (echo "message" && return 1)
}
```

the parentheses create a subshell, and so the return happens in that subshell instead of returning from the function. To avoid this, use `{ }` instead (but note that you need spaces around them and a semicolon before the `}`). Also, using the `function` keyword is nonstandard. Finally, it's conventional to send error messages to stderr instead of stdout. Here's the resulting function definition:

```
F() {
  command || { echo "message" >&2 && return 1; }
}
```

I don't know why the `if ...` version didn't work for you (it did for me), unless you used parentheses there too.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> looks like return returns from if block and not from function,

I am not seeing the same behavior.

I created a file `test-04.sh` that contains the following lines:

```
function F() {
  if [ -f "test-04.sh" ]; then
    echo "message";
    return 1;
  fi
  echo "another message"
}

F
```

When I ran the file through `bash`, I got the following output:

```
message
```

After I changed the contents of the file to

```
function F() {
  if [ ! -f "test-04.sh" ]; then
    echo "message";
    return 1;
  fi
  echo "another message"
}

F
```

and ran it through `bash`, I got the following output.

```
another message
```

Comment: Bash pitfall: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#function_foo.28.29
Also prefer ``[[ ]]`` over ``[ ]``

Answer (score 0):

I have my doubts that return is returning from if block.
Please post your tests how you concluded that!

Your first way of doing it is correct, have a look

```
function F() {
  if [ 1 ]; then 
echo "message"; 
return 1; 
fi
echo "Happy Holiday" ; return 0
}
F ; echo $?
```

Output is

```
message 1
```

If return would have been returning from if then "Happy Holiday 0" Should have been printed.